# Ignore space without deleting space in a string while inserting into SQL database

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, database

I am reading data from a text file into a SQL database using C++ and embedded SQL. 
Here is the text file "employee.txt":

```
1000 Smith Joe 35000.00
```

Where empId=100, empName= "Smith Joe" and empSal = 35000.00.

The statements I've tried so far do not work properly with the space between the first and last name in the employee.txt file. It is reading the space between "Smith" and "Joe" to mean that Smith and Joe are two separate items rather than a string with a space. Here is my code:

```
inFile >> empId;

while (!inFile.eof())
{
    inFile >> empName;
    inFile >> empSal;

    string sql;
    sql = "insert into Employee values (\'"+ empID + "\', \' "+empName+ " \', \'"
           +empSal+ "\')";

    mysql_query(connect, sql.c_str());
    inFile >> empSal;

}
```

If I remove the space from the text file ("SmithJoe" rather than "Smith Joe"), the database populates properly.

I would like to ignore the white-space while reading into the file, without deleting the white-space, in order to put the entire string "Smith Joe" into one cell of the database.

Is there a way to ignore the white space between the two names without deleting the space so that the entire string "Smith Joe" can be read into one cell of the database?

Thankyou

Comment: What does mysql have to do with this? Your problem is only with reading a text file, and what you do with the data after reading it is irrelevant, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are fundamentally screwed. If you use a space to separate the first name from the last name, you cannot tell whether it was the first name or the last name that had a space in it. You cannot know whether "A B C" is "A B","C" or "A","B C". So you can't get both "Dideric van der Waal" (a chemist whose last named contained spaces) and "Ram gopal Qatlam" (a friend of mine whose first name contains a space) right. How do you know whether "Patrick Nielsen Hayden" has a middle name, a first name with a space, or a last name with a space? (Spoiler, his last name has a space.)

Comment: Obligatory reference to [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by reading the empName into two variables like empFirstName and empLastName, then concat them while inserting into database.

Comment: That will fail if the employee's name is "Dideric van der Waal".

Comment: I totally agree with David Schwartz. The input should have some delimiter without which no technique would work forever. Even the split technique will also fail if one more column has to be added to the input in future.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read in the whole line. "**1000 Smith Joe 35000.00**"
2. Find the first space. Split at that space. "**1000**", "**Smith Joe 35000.00**"
3. Find the last space in the remainder of the line. Split at that space. "**1000**", "**Smith Joe**", "**35000.00**"